# What is the Tuya API referring to when they ask for the "schema" in some of their Open API calls?

Tags: api, schema, iot, tuya

I have accessed the Tuya cloud using their API.  I can't use any of the API calls that uses the "schema".  I assume this is the name of my iOS app?  Does anyone have an example of a working call that uses "schema"?

For example I have tried "sensorstat" and "com.status.sensor" while calling API "get user list".  I expected the API to give me a list of users registered through the application.

I get a permission denied response.:
{
    "code": 1106,
    "msg": "permission deny",
    "success": false,
    "t": 1559669799846
}

Comment: I don't have enough point to create a tag for "Tuya".  Can someone add that?

Comment: The answer is that if your app package name is com.aa.bb, your schema is aabb.

Answer (score 1):

The schema is going to be the "Channel Identifier" of your app.

You can find this by:

1. Login to https://iot.tuya.com/
2. Click on "App Service" in the top.
3. Click on "App SDK" on the left.
4. Click on the app you created.
5. At the top you should see your Android Identifier, iOS Identifier and Channel Identifier.